# Rails select_tag will not access belongs_to relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, html-select, belongs-to

I am trying to do a

```
select_tag "employee_compensation_benefits_selection", options_from_collection_for_select(@employees, "id", "entity.name", "1")
```

but entity.name wont work throws an undefined method `entity.name'. "entity" belongs to another model. through an entity_id

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

  include UUIDHelper

  belongs_to :entity
  has_one :status
  has_many :restdays
  has_one :regular_work_period

  validates_presence_of :entity

end

require 'file_size_validator'
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base

  include UUIDHelper

  has_one :access, autosave: true
  has_one :employee, autosave: true
  has_many :contact_detail, autosave: true
  has_many :file_set
  has_many :link_set

  mount_uploader :logo, AvatarUploader
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
  validates_length_of :description, maximum: 256

  validates :logo,
        :file_size => {
            :maximum => 25.megabytes.to_i
        }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you add a method to your employee that you can call, like:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def entity_name
    self.entity.name
  end
end
```

and then:

```
select_tag "employee_compensation_benefits_selection", options_from_collection_for_select(@employees, "id", "entity_name", "1")
```

or you can use a lambda instead of adding a method:

```
select_tag "employee_compensation_benefits_selection", options_from_collection_for_select(@employees, "id", lambda { |employee| employee.entity.name }, "1")
```

Comment: on " lambda { |employee| employee.entity.name)} there is some sort of expected/unexpected newline error?

Comment: @james oh, sorry. Had a typo in the lamda. There was a `)` where it shouldn't be

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to your Employee model:

```
def entity_name
  self.entity.name
end
```

Or you could add a delegate like this to your Employee model:

```
delegate :name, :to => :entity, :prefix => true
```

Then you could do:

```
select_tag "employee_compensation_benefits_selection", options_from_collection_for_select(@employees, "id", "entity_name", "1")
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'Entity' model refers to a table name 'entities' on the database (unless you overwrote the default for the table name). Use "entities.name" instead. This will work if you joined the result @employees = Employer.joins(:entity).